# How to change column values to show different value in bind DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, data-binding, datagridview

I have a `dataGridView`, which is data bound to some `generic List<T>` (while T is some custom class with properties).
The problem is that one of the property is type of `integer`, and it represents minutes.
After binding List to dataGridView, I want that column shows hours, instead of minutes by default.

How to change some column`s behaviour, to use some math over it to show a bit different values?

Do I have to do this in the `DataGridView.CellFormating` event?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, the first one is to manipulate your `Generic List<T>` first, that should be faster than using the second option, iterating through your list on each `RowDataBound Event`.

- **Using `RowDataBound` Event**

  protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
      {
          if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
          {
              int minutes = int.Parse(e.Row.Cells[YourColumnIndex].Text);
              decimal hours = minutes / 60;
              e.Row.Cells[YourColumnIndex].Text = hours.ToString();
          }
      }
- **Using `Evel` Expression**

ASPX Page

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time">
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# ConvertToHours(Eval("Minutes"))%>
            </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind

```
private string ConvertToHours(object objMin)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(objMin) == 1)
    {
        return (int.Parse(objMin) / 60).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

**Another approach.** - do-it-all in single shot.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Time">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Time")) Convert.ToInt32("60")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Update:** As the Question updated, Then for Windows Forms application you should use `DataGridView.CellFormatting Event`

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // If the column is the Time column, check the 
    // value. 
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Time")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
             //Your implementation.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using a windows form.

Comment: @MitjaBonca - ops! Check Updated answer then.